# Git : Start a new project with some commits from an other one

Tags: git

I have this "--bare" project on my server named "WebsiteCore" and every git commit is a feature.

I wish to create a new project with some commits from "WebsiteCore" (I just want some features). I would also like to make an other "--bare" project on my server to work on the new project remotely.

Comment: What do you mean by "every commit is a feature"? Every commit adds a feature?

Comment: Yes, every commit contain a single feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a use case for [`git rebase --interactive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), since it would allow you replay those commits while removing the one you do not want

It also allows you to split a commit which contain some parts relevant to another you want to keep, while removing the rest: not all commits (here "features") you want to keep are fully independent one from another. Some can be build on top of other commits.

So make a branch prior to those commits, replay the "features" branch on top of your branch with a '`git rebase --interactive`' and '`clone --bare`' your repo into a new one on your server.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe use `git cherry-pick`.